TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255] while using enumerate
I do not know why I got this error while using the enumerate environment. The error does not show up if I use the itemize environment.
Please help.

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{boxes} }
%\usetheme{FrankKurt}

%used to customize the size of the frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.0ex,dp=0.6ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}



\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,comment}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\usepackage{enumitem}% to customize the itemize enviroment as showed below
\setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet} 

 
\newlist{encase}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[encase]{label=Case \arabic*:, leftmargin=1.36cm}



\usepackage{enumitem}% used to customize itemize environment

\newcommand{\adots}{\mathinner{\mkern2mu%
        \raisebox{0.1em}{.}\mkern2mu\raisebox{0.4em}{.}%
        \mkern2mu\raisebox{0.7em}{.}\mkern1mu}}

\newenvironment{myitemize}
{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.14in]}
    {\end{itemize} }


 
 

\title[{\makebox[.45\paperwidth]{\hfill%
Section 1.8   \hspace{.2in}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}]{Section 1.8  }


\author[]{
}
\vskip -.5in


\date{}% to not show date





\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

 

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item    abc
        
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}


TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. \end{frame}

Please provide an MWE (complete small document, which can be compiled as it is) which exhibits your problem, Your code fragment not cause reported error.

@Zarko Updated my question.

Don't use enumitem with beamer!

Package enumiitemi˙doesn't work well with beammer, however, at last version of beamer you still can use it. For example, your code reduced to MWE, works fine:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{enumitem}% used to customize itemize environment
\newlist{encase}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[encase]{label=\textcolor{blue}{Case \arabic*:}, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{encase}
        \item    abc
        \item    def
        \item    ghi        
    \end{encase}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Don't use enumitem with beamer. If you need special lists like Case 1: etc., use mini templates:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{boxes} }


%used to customize the size of the frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.0ex,dp=0.6ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\begin{document}    

\begin{frame}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{1.35cm}
    
    normal text
    \begin{enumerate}[{Case~}1:]
        \item    abc
        \item    abc
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Case 1, Case 2 are too far left on the page. How do I add some indent to move them inside?

@hochoi Change \leftmargini to whatever value you like

Thanks. So, the problem all lie in the usage of the enumitem environment? Can you explain why?

@hochoi The enumitem package is incompatible with beamer. Both beamer and enumitem heavily redefine how lists work - in a way which is incompatible to each other. Without knowing which class someone uses, one should never suggest such a risky package like enumitem.

Many thanks for your help!

@hochoi You're welcome!
